# AddOrUpdate works not as expected and produces duplicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, upsert

I'm using Code-First DBContext-based EF5 setup.

In `DbMigrationsConfiguration.Seed` I'm trying to fill DB with default dummy data. To accomplish this task, I use `DbSet.AddOrUpdate` method.

The simplest code to illustrate my aim:

```
j = 0;

var cities = new[]
    {
        "Berlin",
        "Vienna",
        "London",
        "Bristol",
        "Rome",
        "Stockholm",
        "Oslo",
        "Helsinki",
        "Amsterdam",
        "Dublin"
    };
var cityObjects = new City[cities.Length];


foreach (string c in cities)
{
    int id = r.NextDouble() > 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
    var city = new City
        {
            Id = j,
            Name = c,
            Slug = c.ToLowerInvariant(),
            Region = regions[id],
            RegionId = regions[id].Id,
            Reviewed = true
        };
    context.CitySet.AddOrUpdate(cc => cc.Id, city);
    cityObjects[j] = city;
    j++;
}
```

I've tried to use/omit `Id` field as well as to use `Id`/`Slug` property as update selector.

when `Update-Database` is run, `Id` field is ignored and the value is generated automatically by SQL Server and DB is filled with duplicates; `Slug` selector allows duplicates and on subsequent runs produces exceptions (`Sequence contains more than one element`).

Is `AddOrUpdate` method intended to work this way? Should I perform upsert by hand?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First (no answer yet), `AddOrUpdate` can be called with an array of new objects, so you can just create an array of type `City[]` and call `context.CitySet.AddOrUpdate(cc => cc.Id, cityArray);` once.

(edited)

Second, `AddOrUpdate` uses the identifier expression (`cc => cc.Id`) to find cities with the same `Id` as the ones in the array. These cities will be updated. The other cities in the array will be inserted, but their `Id` values will be generated by the database, because `Id` is an identity column. It can not be set by an insert statement. (Unless you set Identity Insert on). So when using `AddOrUpdate` for tables with identity columns you should find another way to identify records because the Id values of existing records are unpredictable.

In you case you used `Slug` as identifier for `AddOrUpdate`, which should be unique (as per your comment). It is not clear to me why that does not update existing records with matching `Slug`s.

I set up a little test: add or update an entity with an Id (iedntity) and a unique name:

```
var n = new Product { ProductID = 999, ProductName = "Prod1", UnitPrice = 1.25 };
Products.AddOrUpdate(p => p.ProductName, n);
SaveChanges();
```

When "Prod1" is not there yet, it is inserted (ignoring Id 999).
If it is and `UnitPrice` is different, it is updated.

Looking at the emitted queries I see that EF is looking for a unique record by name:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
[Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
[Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
WHERE N'Prod1' = [Extent1].[ProductName]
```

And next (when a match is found and `UnitPrice` is different)

```
update [dbo].[Products]
set [UnitPrice] = 1.26
where ([ProductID] = 15)
```

This shows that EF found one record and now uses the key field to do the update.

I hope that seeing this example will shed some light on your situation. Maybe you should monitor the sql statements as well and see if anything unexpected happens there.

Comment: Gert, thank you for trying to help! Actually, City was given the `id=j` which ranges from 0 to 9. You were just tricked by similar variable names. Next, I already mentioned the effect of using Name (in my case, Slug, as it's really unique) - it's letting the duplicated into the DB. Passing all objects as an array didn't yield any progress.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I no longer can verify your it. If anyone from the community will comment under your answer that it helped him/her, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Sorry that it took so long.

Comment: Any idea how the identifier expression would look if it required two fields to uniquely identify the record? I'm thinking p => p.ProductName, p.CategoryName (but of course that doesn't work).

Comment: `p => new { p.ProductName, p.CategoryName }` @Jarvis

Comment: In my case, this code failed when using `context.Set<TEntity>().AddOrUpdate(...)` you have to reference the actual DBSet.

Comment: @BronDavies `context.Set<TEntity>()` is the actual `DbSet`. If anything goes wrong here, it must be something else causing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var paidOutType = new List<PaidOutType>
                {
                    new PaidOutType { PaidOutTypeID = 1, Code = "001", Description = "PAID OUT 1", PType = "1", Amount = 0, IsSalesSummery = true,DayFrom=1,DayTo=31 },
                    new PaidOutType { PaidOutTypeID = 2, Code = "002", Description = "PAID OUT 2", PType = "1", Amount = 0, IsSalesSummery = true,DayFrom=1,DayTo=31 },
                    new PaidOutType { PaidOutTypeID = 3, Code = "002", Description = "PAID OUT 3", PType = "1", Amount = 0, IsSalesSummery = true,DayFrom=1,DayTo=31 },
                };
                paidOutType.ForEach(u => smartPOSContext.PaidOutType.AddOrUpdate(u));
                smartPOSContext.SaveChanges();
```